# boost.multi_index: iterate over an index in reverse order

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-multi-index

I am wondering if we can iterate over Boost.Multi_Index container in reverse order, similar to STL's vector `rbegin()` and `rend()`.

The code below is mostly borrowed from [here](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.multiindex). While iterating over the legs_index (last few lines) and print animal names, the animal names show up in ascending order based on legs count. I need to do the same in descending order.

Any idea how to do that?

Thank you!

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct animal
{
  std::string name;
  int legs;
};

typedef multi_index_container<
  animal,
  indexed_by<
    sequenced<>,
    ordered_non_unique<
      member<
        animal, int, &animal::legs
      >
    >,
    random_access<>
  >
> animal_multi;

int main()
{
  animal_multi animals;

  animals.insert({"cat", 4});
  animals.insert({"shark", 0});
  animals.insert({"spider", 8});

  auto &legs_index = animals.get<1>();
  auto it = legs_index.begin();
  auto end = legs_index.end();
  for (; it != end; ++it)
    std::cout << it->name << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Did you try `rbegin()` and `rend()`?

Comment: hi @TannerSansbury. Yes, I tried. I got a compilation error.

Comment: And does the posted code above compile?

Comment: For what it is worth, `rbegin()` and `rend()` are provided and function as expected.  The compilation errors is likely due to `insert()` expecting two arguments (position and element); consider using `push_back()` instead.  ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00517dcc40c280da))

Comment: I replaced insert with push_back and used rbegin() and rend(). Did not work. I still got compilation error.

Comment: Can you reproduce on coliru?  Does code in the linked demo work?  Expanding the question with compilation errors may help for those unable to reproduce it.

Comment: @TannerSansbury, seems like whether these functions exist or not depends on the indexing technique for a particular index. If I chose `ordered_non_unique` combined with `sequenced`, I get a different interface for the index than what I would get if I chose `hashed_unique` or `hashed_non_unique`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the insert calls:

```
animals.insert(animals.end(), animal_multi::value_type {"cat", 4});
animals.insert(animals.end(), animal_multi::value_type {"shark", 0});
animals.insert(animals.end(), animal_multi::value_type {"spider", 8});
```

Now, just use reverse iterators:

```
auto &legs_index = animals.get<1>();
auto it = legs_index.rbegin();
auto end = legs_index.rend();
for (; it != end; ++it)
  std::cout << it->name << '\n';
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ff9ebf4bd5313be)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct animal
{
  std::string name;
  int legs;
};

typedef multi_index_container<
  animal,
  indexed_by<
    sequenced<>,
    ordered_non_unique<
      member<
        animal, int, &animal::legs
      >
    >,
    random_access<>
  >
> animal_multi;

int main()
{
  animal_multi animals;

  animals.insert(animals.end(), animal_multi::value_type {"cat", 4});
  animals.insert(animals.end(), animal_multi::value_type {"shark", 0});
  animals.insert(animals.end(), animal_multi::value_type {"spider", 8});

  auto &legs_index = animals.get<1>();
  auto it = legs_index.rbegin();
  auto end = legs_index.rend();
  for (; it != end; ++it)
    std::cout << it->name << '\n';
}
```

Prints

```
spider
cat
shark
```

Comment: Alternatively, invert the ordering predicate: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84df3e376d8f5e51)**

Comment: thank you for the effort. 
I do not think that is thought, after some reading and trials and errors I found the problem to be with the choice of indexing technique choices. For example, if you chose `ordered_non_unique` combined with `sequenced` I will get what I want. But with `hashed_unique` I wont be use rbegin or rend on such index.

Comment: @hebbo For the question that was asked, I think this is correct.  The original question makes no mention of hashed indices. The [hash indeces](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html#hash_indices) satisfy the C++ requirement of unordered associative containers, which do not provide reverse iterators, as reverse iteration would produce an equally arbitrary order as forward iteration.